# P8C WS: No Internet

Tags: networking, ethernet

I supposedly built a PC off the ASUS P8C WS motherboard more than six years ago. The dual ethernet ports have been working fine.  Now, neither one of them works, but everything else on the MB seems to work okay...  I tried:

1. Fresh installing Windows 10
2. Fresh installing Windows 8.0
3. Fresh installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
4. Using the MS Windows Network troubleshooting tool which constantly reports "'Ethernet X' doesn't have a valid IP configuration.'
5. Completely disabling the onboard network cards and using a third party USB to Ethernet adapter from Best Buy marketed by Insignia
6. Swapping out ethernet cables
7. Connecting directly to my Cox Internet provided SB6182 Modem via http://192.168.100.1 
   (my P8C WS can't see the SB6182 at the said address but the computer I'm typing this question on can...)
8. Reinstalling drivers
9. Successfully flashing my BIOS
10. Resetting the BIOS via jumper *and* pulling the battery *and* external "115" Volt Power Cable
11. Various other "tricks" I've seen on the internet that I can't remember right now.

The modem works okay for the machine I am typing this question on, but it does not work for the P8C WS MB even when I use a third party ethernet USB adapter by Insignia.

What's got me confused as a "deer staring into headlights" is that:

1. I've tried several clean OSes
2. The MB seems fine
   and
3. I'm using a brand new ethernet USB adapter at this point
   (Onboard ethernet is now disabled in the BIOS out of frustration)

I would think one of the last three options would have resolved this issue by now...

Anyone happen to know what else I can try or forgot to list here?

Comment: The problem appears to have something to do with the fact that SB6182 Modem from Cox is getting confused due to my lack of home networking skills.  Apparently, I'm configuring multiple machines wrong in my home network.  The modem then seems to take an affinity to one of the machines, then the modem doesn't like to work with other machines until I turn off all other network devices and connect the said "rejected" machines one by one to the modem directly after it has been powered off for some time.  The modem is actually made by Motorola but I bought it from Cox.

Comment: I did eventually get the P8C W2 onboard Lan working BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by your description. It is reasonable at 6 years that onboard network cards could fail - dual ports likely share a controller.

Now you installed several clean operating systems with no change, so it is not OS.

Now not Motherboard you say, except that the USB controller is on the motherboard and USB Ethernet adapters do not work.

So I would conclude from the above a Motherboard Hardware Issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on.  I just got the both the Insignia USB to Ethernet adapter *and* one of my P8C WS Lan sockets to communicate HTML with an internal webserver at http://192.168.0.254   (No TLS or SSL).  To do that, I had to manually set the IP to 192.168.0.1 and the Subnet Mask to 255.255.255.0.   I wonder if there is something wrong with the configuration the P3C WS is using for the SB6182 from Cox.  What I really don't get here is why reinstalling the operating systems aren't taking care of this for me automatically...

Comment: It is not likely a COX issue if USB Ethernet does not work and Network Cards no longer work. Your motherboard controller circuits appear to have failed.

Comment: Yes, but I can receive HTML from an internal webserver (via IP) with one of the onboard controllers on the P8C WS.  Unless my P8C WS is intermittently wacky, this sounds like some sort of weird "software" configuration issue now.  I would have thought that reinstalling the OSes would have taken care of the software issues though.

Comment: Reinstalling a modern os will indeed fix issues like this. New os's do not (hardly ever) have weird software configurations. So from here it continues to look like a hardware error of some sort.